# BigQuery gives "Missing whitespace" error when creating a Materialized View

Tags: google-bigquery

## The error

When trying to create a Materialized View, I get the error `Syntax error: Missing whitespace between literal and alias at [1:42]`. The same error is not flagged in the FROM for any queries that I've run, so far.  The issue seems to be the character after the numeric part of my (auto-generated) project ID.

*Project ID changed to protect my real ID, but the format is the same*

## My code

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW  my-project-1234a.firestore_export.viewTestBQ
AS SELECT name, SUM(clicks) AS sum_clicks
FROM  my-project-1234a.firestore_export.TestBQ_raw_changelog
GROUP BY 1
```

## What I've tried

- Putting single quotes, double quotes and backticks around the Project ID
- Putting single quotes, double quotes and backticks around the whole `${projectId}.${dataset}.${view_name}` string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery uses special backlits when selecting an object. Consider the approach:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW  `my-project-1234a.firestore_export.viewTestBQ` AS 
SELECT name, SUM(clicks) AS sum_clicks
FROM  `my-project-1234a.firestore_export.TestBQ_raw_changelog`
GROUP BY 1
```

And if this doesn’t seem to work, also consider the following approach:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW `my-project-a1234.firestore_export.viewTestBQ` AS
SELECT name, SUM(clicks) AS sum_clicks 
FROM  `my-project-a1234.firestore_export.TestBQ_raw_changelog`
GROUP BY 1
```

As you can see, the difference between my two recommendations is that, in your project, you will need to start with a letter followed by numbers instead of numbers followed by a letter.

Comment: I had to create a new project and ensure that I created it in GCP, then added it to Firebase, rather than the other way round.  That gave me tighter control over the project ID.  It does seems crazy that BQ ca't cope with this naming format, even when surrounded by quotes or backticks.